# How often does this cron job run?

Tags: cron

How often will the following cron job run:

```
*/5 * * * *   root    /shell/my_script.sh
```

Answer (score 7):

Every five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should run every five minutes.

Check out ["man 5 crontab"](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Every five minutes of every hour, every day, every month, forever.